# Google doc add for read only mode

Tags: documentation, readonly

I am using Google doc for storing My education contents.whenever I open any doc it always opens in  editing mode, by mistake if any key pressed it saved to the document. Is there feature like opening the google doc in Read only mode by default or any google add on for reading the Google doc.It would be great if some one help on this.New hacks for reading also much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

finally found answer myself.Just install kami pdf plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kami-extension-pdf-and-do/ecnphlgnajanjnkcmbpancdjoidceilk?hl=en in drive and open the doc using kami pdf